# How to express strong decision?

Tags: grammar, future-tense

The following context is given:

Two friends are talking about by-time. One of them want to express *very strong* decision of to swim the next year. How it can be said?

My understanding:
I think it is a fixed arrangement. This implies we can use Present Progressive to express that:

> I'm swimming the next year.

But how to express **very strong** decision? Will this sentence express very strong decision, if we *emphasize* ***to be+ swimming*** during the speaking?

Comment: *"I'm swimming the next year."* is weird! Also, what do you mean by *swimming?* Taking part in a competition or learning swimming?

Comment: @MaulikV learning swimming

Comment: @MaulikV Why is it weird? I thought that Present Progressive is commonly used for fixed arrangements. How do you said that?

Comment: I'll nurture your belief! *I'm learning swimming next year for sure.*

Comment: @MaulikV That is, _for sure_ can express strong decision.

Comment: Of course yes because you wrote *strong decision!* :) *I'll...* also works but as I said, since you already believe that PP is common for fixed things...I said it that way. I remember that I gave an example of *train* for present progressive in some answer, was that your question?

Comment: @MaulikV I checked the question about train. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/usage-of-the-present-simple-and-the-future-progressive. I couldn't find your example.

Comment: That's the different question. I had explained about using PP in case of things that are happening for sure - *the train is leaving in five minutes*. Anyway, you already know this so no need to discuss it further! :)

Comment: Present be-Ving is OK for a future action in the **near** future, with next year it really sounds weird, even if decision is strong, as you say. I'd much rather say "I'll learn (be learning) to swim next year".

Comment: @Laure MaulikV said that "for sure" had used for strong decision. Is "I'll learn to swim next year for sure." correct?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Yes, that's correct. *For sure* means the same here as *definitely* or *certainly*. Note also that *I'll* is a contraction of *I will*, placing it in the future tense.

Comment: It's correct but not necessary if you use will, will here shows a strong decision has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As Laure notes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/how-to-express-strong-decision#comment51919_27597), next year can be considered a bit too far in the future for present tenses. However, it would not be uncommon to hear something like this in colloquial conversation:

> Next year, I'm learning how to swim.

I prefer using *will* here, because the action is in the not-so-near future. *Will* also conveys a powerful sense of certainty or determination when properly stressed:

> I ***will*** be learning how to swim next year.

You can also add *definitely* or a similar emphasizer to highlight the strength of the decision.

I've stuck with progressive tenses as that's what's mentioned explicitly in the question. They suggest that the learning will be a somewhat involved or longer process, and also leave open some possibility that it will not be completed by the end of the next year.

Comment: "Will be learning" isn't a common construction in spoken English. Simple future tense "I will swim" is actually quite emphatic to an English speaker.

Comment: What about "I'm going to take swim lessons next year"?. Is not "be+going+to" for plans?

Comment: @rewobs Yes, that indicates a plan.

Comment: @wordsmythe As I wrote, I left it in progressive tense because that was a distinct choice made by the OP and carries different nuances than the simple. *Will be gerund* is a common construction where I'm from; perhaps that's a regional difference. And "quite emphatic" is an overstatement. Naked, unemphasized *will* does indicate a definite decision, but it does not suggest the sort of determination and resolve that were requested.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, I don't think the OP was making a choice so much as asking if their understanding was correct. My interpretation (and I'll grant that this will differ depending on where one is in the English-speaking world) of "will be swimming" matches the idea of an appointment, but not the idea of "strong decision."

Answer (score 3):

*Swimming* is not synonymous with *learning to swim*: you would have to explicitly state that.

Colloquially, I would say:

> I'm definitely learning to swim next year.

You might also say:

> I'm definitely going to learn to swim next year.

*Definitely* implies a firm decision.

Answer (score 1):

One could also say "by next year, I will have learned to swim."

Comment: This meaning is slightly different from the original: *having finished learning* how to swim by next year (yours) versus *being in the process of learning* next year (question's). But I do agree that the use of *will* is called for here.

Answer (score 0):

If you say,

"I'm learning to swim next year."

It usually implies you have already enrolled in a course, paid your fee, unavailable.

Likewise if a woman declines a man's offer to go out on a date on Saturday night claiming the old, *put-down* excuse, "I'm washing my hair on Saturday Night," she means that her hair-washing plans are pretty much already a foregone conclusion.