# The simple present for future?

Tags: present-tense, future-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I did search on the internet. but I couldn't still understand well how to use simple present **for future**. every grammar book says "simple present is used for events in the future which are 'timetabled, scheduled"

1. What does here *timetable / schedule* mean?
2. What is the difference between present simple (when used for future) and present continuous (when used for future)?

   *For example*, Difference between  the sentence

   > The sun **rises** at 6.00 tomorrow

   and

   > The sun **is rising** at 6.00 tomorrow

Comment: [Related question 1](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27533/2127), [related question 2](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27431/2127)

Comment: See also [*What's will?* on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=897).

Comment: @snailboat Is it true that [only some verbs](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-using-the-present-simple-to-talk-about-the-future/) can be used with simple present to talk about a future?

Comment: @Dinusha The link you've provided is incorrect.  Verbs which aren't on that list can appear in the present simple form with a future time meaning, for example when discussing future plans: "Tomorrow I **walk** ten miles, and the day after I **walk** twenty."  *Walk* does not appear on the list the author presents.  For another example, see *rise* in "The sun **rises** at 6:00 tomorrow" from CopperKettle's answer below.  This verb doesn't appear on their list, either.

Comment: @snail - Yikes! If only that column said, "Verbs like the ones below..." instead of "Only the verbs below..." I don't see how that blogger can include the word _fly_ yet omit the verb _drive_: _We drive to Paris next week_. If it works for _fly_, it should work for _drive_, too.

Answer (score 5):

> 1.What does here timetable / schedule mean?

Let's take the sentence

> The sun **rises** at 6.00 tomorrow.

*Timetable* means that you personally played no part in causing the sun to rise at 6.00 tomorrow. The sun follows the laws of nature, like a train following a timetable. It will likely follow the same laws for a long time yet, and have been following them for a long time.

Imagine a person saying to his friend:

> The train to Yuma **stops** in our town at 3:10 tomorrow.

The person is not the owner of the train company and he has not decided the time of the arrival of the train. He had consulted the timetable on the wall, a timetable probably hanging there for months or years.

Let's now look at

> The sun is **rising** at 6.00 tomorrow

The sentence is not very natural. Looking up "the sun is rising at * tomorrow" on Google brings up only 34 results, all seemingly related to the discussion of tenses in English.

The Present Progressive is used to refer to future events that have some "present reality". We usually employ this tense in discussing our personal plans.

Imagine I've just decided to wake up at 6:00 tomorrow:

> Off with this laziness of mine! I'm **rising** at 6:00 tomorrow.

So, in a fantasy novel some wizard might say:

> (wizard) Thanks to my magic, the sun is **rising** at 6:00 tomorrow!
>    (wizard's apprentice) But this time of the year, the sun **rises** at 7:00!
>   (wizard) See how powerful my magic is - tomorrow, the sun is **rising** a whole hour ahead of its usual *schedule*/*timetable*!

---

Reference: Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, Unit 214: "Future(4): Present Progressive"