# Does not arrive or won't arrive?

Tags: future

Did you use the correct address ?I am really worried that the parcel **does not arrive**  .

Is it better to use won't arrive  future instead present in this example.

Comment: It is not an if sentence

Comment: There's an error in your sentence.  There should be a question mark after address, and then a new sentence.  See [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/27548/68154) to another question about using the simple present tense for future plans/scheduled events. The delivery/arrival of a parcel is a planned/scheduled event.

Comment: So present can fit in my example

Comment: Or the past tense: I am worried because the parcel has not arrived.

Comment: The simple present is fine here. It's a scheduled/panned event. Other examples: Let me know when the parcel arrives. Q: Has the parcel arrived yet? A: No, it doesn't arrive until tomorrow

Comment: I don't find the OP's sentence idiomatic. "I'm worried that it won't/may not arrive" or, as Weather Vane suggests, "...because it hasn't arrived [yet]".

Comment: so why not present  ? Perhaps present  would mean that it is something happening most of the time , it is not a fact but a probability that it won't arrive

Comment: I agree with Kate, it does not work here and is not grammatical.  It is used for short actions occuring now, which is not the case really with the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you've got a keen eye for detail, **Yves**! In the context of your sentence, "won't arrive" is indeed the better choice. Let's break it down:

Saying "does not arrive" is using the present tense, which implies a **general statement** or a **habitual action**. It doesn't quite fit when you're talking about a specific event happening in the future, like waiting for a parcel.

"Won't arrive" uses the future tense, which is perfect for expressing a **concern or doubt** about something that hasn't happened yet, as your parcel reaches you.

So, if you're expressing worry about the future arrival of your parcel, you'd say, "I am really worried that the parcel won't arrive." This shows you're concerned about a future event and it sounds more natural in this scenario.

Remember:

"Does not arrive" = General or habitual action.
"Won't arrive" = Specific concern about the future.

Answer (score 0):

- I am really worried that those parcels don't ever arrive on time. [general, present simple]
- I am really worried that the parcel didn't arrive [yesterday or a point in time is meant].
- I am really worried that the parcel has not arrived. [past tense, unspecific as to when].
- I am really worried that the parcel won't arrive. [refers to a future time]

For French speakers, it is important to remember that the present simple is a generality. And that present perfect signals time that is unspecific in the past and that simple past is for finished actions in general. It's tough because French has no present perfect.

- I speak Chinese but don't when I go to Singapore. [general]
- I speak Chinese but *haven't spoken it* in ages. [in ages, recently, frequently and other time adverbs]
- I speak Chinese but *didn't [speak it] this time* in Singapore.[the trip is over.]